# ReactJS components fade in when they are in viewport

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do fade-in blog posts with ReactJS. My initial idea was to just add scroll event for each `<Post>` component and check if it's in the browser view (`window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > this.post.offsetTop`)

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.scrollHandler = this.scrollHandler.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      fadeIn: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler);
    this.scrollHandler();
  }

  scrollHandler() {
    if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > this.post.offsetTop) {
      this.setState({
        fadeIn: styles.fadeIn,
      });

      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollHandler);
    }
  }

  render()

    return (
      <div className={`${styles.post} ${this.state.fadeIn}`} ref={(div) => { this.post = div; }}>
        Awesome article
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`fadeIn` styles just change the opacity of element. Everything is working.
Now question - is there better way of doing this? I don't like the idea of creating for each element scroll event. IMO there should be only one scroll event (for example in parent component), that will provide window position data and  components should compare this with their top position. But unfortunately I don't know how to implement this with ReactJS.

Comment: I think what you're doing is fine for the desired effect, but an opinionated response:  I really despise fadein/out on scroll.  IMO you should never substitute one user action with another, and causing fadein/out on scroll is essentially swapping the user's scroll wheel with a list of navigation anchors to what are essentially completely different pages.  If your usecase demands it, go for it, but I would always push back against that kind of styling.

Comment: To bo honest, I don't see any problem with fadeIn effect (maybe you missunderstand me). But anyway - I can imagine other stuff that you can do on scroll event for several elements (like sticky elements etc.) so the "problem" is more general.

Answer (score 0):

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isScroll: false
    }
}

handleScroll = () => {
    let winHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (window.pageYOffset > winHeight){
      this.setState({
        isScroll: true
      })

    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        isScroll: false
      })

    }
  }

  scrollUp = () => {
    window.scroll({
      top: 0, 
      behavior: 'smooth' 
    })

  }

componentDidMount(){
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}

render() {
      return (
            {this.state.isScroll &&
                <div className="scroll-up" onClick={this.scrollUp}>top</div>
            }
        );
}
```